# hiding extra contents in DIV with following dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i need to hide extra text from my DIV element following dots (...)

**I m using**

```
<div style="width:200px; height:2em; line-height:2em; overflow:hidden;" id="box">
 this is text this is text this is text this is text
</div>
```

**Result**

it hides the rest of the content which overflows DIV

but i wants that if it has to hide then three dots `...` should be placed at the end else not

**Output Need**

this is text this is text this is te...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using `text-overflow:ellipsis`:

http://jsfiddle.net/FXHA3/

```
.ellipsis {
    width:200px;
    height:2em;
    line-height:2em;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called ellipsis

Heres an example of how its used:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple javascript for that, especially when you use jQuery:

```
jQuery('#box').html(jQuery('#box').html().substr(0,30) + '...');
```

This will show the first 30 characters and 3 dots

Comment: it is good but what if the content length is less than 30 ? will it show dots in this case ??

Comment: You can always add an if-statement around it where you check the length